# Is there an SVN command that will allow me to confirm and skip windows (like Confirm Update! and Committing Version to File) that pop up?

Tags: python, svn, cmd, buildbot

I created a Buildbot system and am using SVN with it and would like to do updates to my SVN without having to click the confirmations for when the update finished and committing version file. The buildbot system would just take in a command that would allow it to do all confirmation of updates and committing continuously without having said windows pop up.

Is there an SVN command that will allow me to confirm and skip windows (like Confirm Update! and Committing Version to File) that pop up?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have anything "pop up" if you're using the correct tools for automating your process. You're probably using `TortoiseProc.exe`, which is advertised as *not* being suitable for unattended/automated usage. `TortoiseProc.exe` is not the replacement for `svn.exe` client.

The command-line client `svn` is the correct way to automate Subversion client tasks (`svn update`, `svn commit`, etc.). Or if you're already working within a Python script, try one of the Python libraries for Subversion.

Comment: Why PySVN? SWIG Python bindings are great and are part of SVN.